# How to add responses from an Answers table in an ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add responses from an `Answers` table in a survey tool I am modifying, to create an edit view so users can continue a survey where they left off.

Here's what I have so far in the controller which pulls all the questions from a particular survey:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int surveyId)
    {
        var survey = _db.Surveys
                        .Where(s => s.Id == surveyId)
                        .Select(s => new
                            {
                                Survey = s,
                                Questions = s.Questions
                                             .Where(q => q.IsActive)
                                             .OrderBy(q => q.Priority)
                            })
                         .AsEnumerable()
                         .Select(x =>
                             {
                                 x.Survey.Questions = x.Questions.ToList();
                                 return x.Survey;
                             })
                         .Single();

        return View(survey);
    }
```

I want to add any potential responses from an `Answers` table (columns to include are `Value` and `Comment`) with a specific `responseId` in that table. So first I'd need to pull the specific `responseId` into the controller.

It's also likely there may not be a 1 to 1 relationship with `Questions` to `Answers`, so I'd need to be able to account for that. In other words, there may be more `Questions` listed in the survey, than answers provided in the `Answers` table. So on the view, I will need to check for Null, etc.

I've tried a few things but I keep getting errors or I'm just making it more complex than I think it needs to be.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am one of those that answers their own question...I was able to do with this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int surveyId, int id)
    {
        var survey = _db.Surveys
            .Where(s => s.Id == surveyId)
            .Select(s => new
            {
                Survey = s,
                Questions = s.Questions
                    .Where(q => q.IsActive)
                    .OrderBy(q => q.Priority)
                    .Select(q => new
                    {
                        Question = q,
                        Answers = _db.Answers
                            .Where(a => a.QuestionId == q.Id && a.ResponseId == id)
                            .ToList()
                    })
            })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(x =>
            {
                x.Survey.Questions = x.Questions.Select(q =>
                {
                    q.Question.Answers = q.Answers;
                    return q.Question;
                }).ToList();
                return x.Survey;
            })
            .Single();
        return View(survey);
    }
```